# "sortedArrayHint" method of NSArray class, what is the purpose of this method and how is it used?

Tags: objective-c

Question is the same as the title.
("sortedArrayHint" method of NSArray class, what is the purpose of this method and how is it used)

I read documentation but the explanation is not clear.

Please explain the purpose of this method and its usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is simple. Assume you have a large array that should always be sorted. Changing or inserting even one element means you have to resort the array. Sorting is costly.

The method `-[NSArray sortedArrayHint]` can be called on an already sorted array in order to get private internal data that can be used to speed up a sort of the same array given that only a small change has been made.

Usage is simple:

1. Get and store the hint from the original sorted array using `-[NSArray sortedArrayHint]`.
2. After a small change; resort using `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:]` with the stored hint.
3. After a large change; resort using `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:]`, and get a new hint.

What is a small, or large, change is something you must measure with Instruments.

I never use this myself, since I have found it more effective to use my own categories on `NSArray` and `NSMutabelArray` for sorted inserts, that uses a binary search, on sorted array. My code is available as open source here: https://github.com/Jayway/CWFoundation

Comment: Your answer has been a great help to me.

Comment: Is reason of using "sortedArrayHint" to speed up?

Comment: @user868754 - Yes, just as the documentation clearly states this is for performance reasons. I will not, and do not want to, write the code for you. It's two method calls that Xcode will give you full code completion for. If that is a problem for you, then me giving you a snippet to cope and paste is only a disservice to you.

Comment: One significant caveat from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:): `[sortedArrayHint] assumes that items in the array implement a -hash method...and that the hash function is a "good" hash function`